# Wronskian of Airy functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, wronskian

I am trying to show that that the Airy functions defined below satisfy: $W[Ai(x),Bi(x)]=1/\pi$.

$$Ai(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \cos(t^3/3+xt)dt$$

$$Bi(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \bigg[ \exp(-t^3/3+xt)+\sin(t^3/3+xt)\bigg]dt $$

I tried to compute it directly but I got stuck, here's the last term I got:

$$Ai(x)Bi'(x)-Ai'(x)Bi(x) = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\bigg[ \int_0^\infty \cos(t^3/3+xt)dt \int_0^\infty \bigg( s\exp(-s^3/3+xs)+s\cos(s^3/3+xs)\bigg) ds + \int_0^\infty \sin(t^3/3+xt)tdt\int_0^\infty \bigg(\exp(-s^3/3+xs)+\sin(s^3/3+xs)\bigg)ds \bigg]$$

I don't see how to proceed from here, I guess I need complex integration contour but how exactly?

Thanks.
I want also to show that $Bi(x),Bi'(x)>0 \forall x>0$, and to conclude the asymptotic identities:
$$Bi(x) \sim \pi^{-1/2}x^{-1/4}\exp(2/3 x^{3/2})$$

$$Bi'(x)\sim \pi^{-1/2}x^{1/4}\exp(2/3 x^{3/2})$$

Comment: A simpler to do it is to directly compute $W[Ai(x=0),Bi(x=0)]$ since from the airy equation we already know that it is independent of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Airy differential equation it is straightforward to show :
$$Ai''(x)=x\:Ai(x)\quad\text{and}\quad Bi''(x)=x\:Bi(x)$$
Let $\quad W(x)=Ai(x)Bi'(x)-Ai'(x)Bi(x)$
$$\frac{dW}{dx}=Ai'(x)Bi'(x)+Ai(x)Bi''(x)-Ai'(x)Bi'(x)-Ai''(x)Bi(x)$$
$$\frac{dW}{dx}=xAi(x)Bi(x)-xAi(x)Bi(x)=0$$
Thus $\quad W(x)=$constant.

Computing $\quad W(0)=Ai(0)Bi'(0)-Ai'(0)Bi(0)\quad$ leads to the constant=$\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: Can you show me how to compute the integrals for when $x=0$? and how to show the asymptotic identities of $Bi(x)$

Comment: See : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html

Comment: JJacquelin, I can see that there's a calculation of the integrals at $x=0$ but not of the asymptotic identities in my first OP.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist : I didn't answer to the question of asymptotics. See http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryBi/06/02/01/01/ for the asymptotic series of $Bi(x)$. Differentiate for $Bi'(x)$.